# scheme: rotation function is not working

Tags: rotation, scheme

```
(define rotate
    (lambda (ls)
            (define subrotate
                    (lambda (head tail res)
                            (if (null? tail)
                                    res
                                    (subrotate (append head (list (car tail)))
                                               (cdr tail)
                                               (cons (append tail head) res)))))
            (if (null? ls)
                    ls
                    (subrotate '() ls '())))) (rotate '(a b c d e))
```

I want to make function that if list (a b c d e), print ((a b c d e) (b c d e a) (c d e a b) (d e a b c) (e a b c d)) but when I execute that function, it prints (e a b c d) (d e a b c) .......

I think this function will activate like

tail | head | res

'() | (a b c d e) | '()

a | (b c d e) | (b c d e a)

(a b) | (c d e) | (c d e a b)

(a b c) | (d e) | (d e a b c)

(a b c d) | (e) | (e a b c d)

(a b c d e) | () | (a b c d e)

and I expect it only print (a b c d e) but result is not. How can I modify this and why it prints every rotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way you're adding new elements to the output list. This should fix it:

```
(define rotate
  (lambda (ls)
    (define subrotate
      (lambda (head tail res)
        (if (null? tail)
            res
            (subrotate (append head (list (car tail)))
                       (cdr tail)
                       (append res (list (append tail head))))))) ; modified
    (if (null? ls)
        ls
        (subrotate '() ls '()))))
```

Alternatively, you could simply `reverse` the output list:

```
(define rotate
  (lambda (ls)
    (define subrotate
      (lambda (head tail res)
        (if (null? tail)
            (reverse res) ; modified
            (subrotate (append head (list (car tail)))
                       (cdr tail)
                       (cons (append tail head) res)))))
    (if (null? ls)
        ls
        (subrotate '() ls '()))))
```

And just for fun, here's a more compact implementation of the same algorithm, this time using a named `let`:

```
(define (rotate ls)
  (let subrotate ((head '()) (tail ls) (res '()))
    (if (null? tail)
        (reverse res)
        (subrotate (append head (list (car tail)))
                   (cdr tail)
                   (cons (append tail head) res)))))
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but also I want to know how this code print every rotated lists. I think it should print only 1 list

Comment: The part with the `(append tail head)` creates each one of the sublists, and they get accumulated in the `res` parameter at each call of the recursion - `res` acting as an accumulator for the output list

Comment: Thanks. Implementation using named let also interesting.